# Flutter audioHandler audio_service package

Tags: flutter, audio, just-audio, audio-service

I would like to add the following example [https://suragch.medium.com/background-audio-in-flutter-with-audio-service-and-just-audio-3cce17b4a7d](https://suragch.medium.com/background-audio-in-flutter-with-audio-service-and-just-audio-3cce17b4a7d/) a button that replaces the playlist with another one and plays it.

I created a function that removes all the songs from the previous playlist and loads the new one.
However, I can't get it to play.
How do I do this?

```
void changeAndPlayPlaylist() async {
  final pageManager = getIt<PageManager>();
  pageManager.removeAll();
  await pageManager.loadPlaylist2();
  pageManager.play;
}
```

If instead I make two buttons; one that replaces and one that plays works correctly.

```
void changePlaylist() async {
  final pageManager = getIt<PageManager>();
  pageManager.removeAll();
  await pageManager.loadPlaylist2();
}


void play() {
  final pageManager = getIt<PageManager>();
  pageManager.play();
}
```

Thanks for your help

I would have expected that combining the two functions into one would work